# Windows 10 hangs on Ctrl+C

Tags: windows-10

I have been using this system for some time now. But not a week ago I  started getting this issue. Whenever I try to use the keyboard shortcut (Ctrl+C) to copy a text to clipboard and use Ctrl+V to paste it in a different application, my system just hangs for so many seconds. I am not sure what is causing this issue. Any suggestion is appreciated.

My configuration:
RAM: 4 GB
Processor : I3 Intel

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have sufficient free memory, this happens in 2 situations:

- The amount of data you want to copy is very large.
- The data contains various special characters that are harder to interpret (specific languages, non-ASCII chars, etc).

Copying things like the above from a browser like chrome or firefox makes things even slower.

Comment: I have plenty of memory free and all I am trying to do is copy around 10 to 20 plain English words. My machine hangs just for this.

Comment: Where do you copy from ? Is there any font formatting ?

Comment: Lets say I want to copy a plain text sentence. Even to do this, the system hangs. There is no formatting involved.

Comment: In that case, there is a suspicion that you may have a key logger or some type of malware.

Comment: But I have symantec installed and updated. If it is not detecting the malware how do I find this guy who is creating the issue?

Comment: It's a complex method which involved analyzing running tasks and processes. Such a thing may be considered a valid program and therefore will not be detected by many antivirus applications. An easy thing you can do is install some anti-malware like malwarebytes and Hitman Pro. Install and run scans with them in this order.